# Добавить класс по условию VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, framework, vue.js

Хочется сделать красиво, придерживаясь логики VUE.JS

Что-то похожее на это:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" v-for="item in items" :class="active:item.id==n"  href="#">
{{item.id}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. item должен быть "объектом"
2. Все дело в скобках

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529823/how-to-add-class-on-vue-js-2

`<a class="nav-item nav-link" v-for="item in items" :class="{'active':item.id==n}"  href="#">
{{item.id}}
</a>`